I bought an 07 Tucson V6 awd with aftermarket catalytic converter and no O2 sensor bung hole and a Y bar blocking access from bottom. Help!
My Tucson runs fairly well, but it seems a little weak over all, and I often can smell a rich fuel mixture, and I suspect that I am breathing in the fumes.  I bought the car five weeks ago with a new inspection sticker and the engine light on (imagine that), and the diagnostic tests pointed to mainly the MAF sensor but also the 02 sensor (which was not a surprise since the owner told me that because the cat was stolen while in his possession, there is an after-market cat with no bung hole and thus it has no 02 sensor).  I was surprised when the engine light disappeared after replacing the MAF sensor.  I strongly suspect that over time the MAF sensor will get messed up again -- accompanied with the symptoms of an even more weakness and light brief sputtering and occasional stalling when stopped at a stoplight or when going slowly into or out of a parking space--ALL DUE TO THE After-market CAT and the MISSING 02 SENSOR. There was a noticeable and still continuing improvement after installing the MAF sensor.  But how long will the good times last, and will I die from lung cancer from inhailing a strong fuel mixture? And most of all, is it worth it for me to spend $1000 or more on putting in an OEM CAT?  I am considering it en though I would probably have to take out a loan to do it. Hoping to hear from experienced Hyundai Tucson mechanics to enlighten me with smart advice.

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Your '07 Tucson V6 uses three catalytic converters and four O2 sensors; one on each exhaust manifold/catalytic converter with O2 sensor in front(precat) and behind(postcat) the catcons  and a third catcon without O2 sensor.

Raw fuel odors may be from a damaged/leaking metal fuel rail/fittings on the engine, worn fuel test valve core, leak in one or several injectors/fittings, etc. Someone familiar with EFI fuel pressures, measuring pressures with a pressure gauge, may determine if a leak exists.
There may also be a possibility of one or both main catcons disintegrating internally, creating blockage of exhaust gases, in effect strangling exhaust flow that can reduce engine power. A quick test for damaged catcons; removing the upstream/precat O2 sensors with a brief drive. Exhaust will be loud but if engine power suddenly increases, one or both catcons are damaged, blocking exhaust flow. A restricted catcon unable to flow exhaust freely while converting exhaust gases may leak unburned fuel mimicking a fuel leak. Be aware that HOT exhaust gases coming out from the O2 bung may burn/melt nearby plastics (wires, panels, etc) and a temporary exhaust deflector (soup can, sheet metal, etc) may be needed to redirect hot exhaust.
Worn out precat O2 sensors, the ones used as direct feedback to the EFI ecm determining air/fuel mixtures may cause more fuel use resulting in unburned fuel entering the exhaust system, coming out the tail pipe smelling of fuel. Excessive unburned fuel can create damaging catcon situations of prematurely burning them out. Some scenarios may or may not trigger error codes. Each vehicle manufacturer has emissions warranty on emissions parts for 50k miles+. Afterwards, owners are responsible for emissions parts wearing out whether error codes occur or not.


